How can I detect if a document is successfully rendered in Office Online Server using PowerShell?
I am able to pick a document of my choosing from a SharePoint document library using web API calls and send it for rendering.
function Get-SpOosDocumentResponse {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [string]$SiteCollectionUrl,
    [string]$DocLibraryName,
    [string]$FolderPath = '.',
    [string]$DocumentName
  )

  $RestApiUrl = "$SiteCollectionUrl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl" +
    "('$DocLibraryName/$FolderPath')/Files"

  $ShpFolderResponse = Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri $RestApiUrl `
    -UseDefaultCredentials `
    -Method Get `
    -Headers @{
      "Accept" = "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }

  $Files = $ShpFolderResponse.d.results

  $DocId = $Files | where Name -eq $DocumentName | select UniqueId

  if (!$DocId) {
    Write-Error "$DocumentName not found." -ErrorAction Stop
  }

  $WopiUrl = "$SiteCollectionUrl/_layouts/WopiFrame2.aspx" +
    "?sourcedoc={$DocId}&action=view"

  $WopiResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $WopiUrl -UseDefaultCredentials

  return $WopiResponse

}


But I can't find any good way to analyze the response if the rendering was successful, using PowerShell, since the rendering seems to be taking place in the web browser with the use of javascript.
I can't even detect if the WOPI-bindings are broken, using client-side access, since still no errors are generated that I'm able to detect.

Try using Invoke-RestMethod instead.  The issue is that an HTTP response is being returned with Invoke-WebRequest before the java is completing so you do not get any errors but also do not get the entire results.

Using Invoke-RestMethod only generates an error in response. $WopiRespons.html.body.form contains error.aspx?sourcedoc=%7b%40%7bUniqueId%3d3e6f83aa-1609-4e0c-9e22-07d54993698e%7d%7d&action=view (the GUID in the result has been anonymized).

The answer to this question is to use a web testing framework such as Selenium.
Selenium is supported by all major suppliers of web browsers and they release a Selenium version (webdriver) along with their regular releases of Chrome, MS Edge, Firefox etc.
Selenium is then accessed through libraries written in .Net, Python, Java etc.
PowerShell actually do have a Selenium module that wraps .Net Selenium (the project is looking for new maintainers).
To get this to work, you have to replace the webdriver provided with the module with the version that fits your current web browser of choice.
All the selenium commands uses the Se-prefix.
The commands I've explored so far are:

Start-SeDriver - Starts a web browser controlled by Selenium
Set-SeUrl - Navigates to the URL requested
Switch-SeFrame - Changes focus to specified iFrame
Get-SeElement -By Id - Fetches an element based on Id
Get-SeElement -By XPath - Filters out any elements based on the XPath specified
Stop-SeDriver - Stops the web browser

To get all elements available in the web page use
$elements = Get-SeElement -By XPath "//*"
To get the Id of a specific element use
$elements[23].GetAttribute('id')
To help you out with finding out what elements is of interest in the web page, I highly recommend using a web browser extension such as Selenium IDE (abandoned project) or Katalon Recorder.
So a working example of checking if the OOS is loading could be.
$SiteCollectionUrl = 'https://my.site'
$DocLibraryName = 'Shared documents'
$FolderPath = '.'
$DocumentName = 'Document.docx'

$RestApiUrl = "$SiteCollectionUrl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl" +
  "('$DocLibraryName/$FolderPath')/Files"

$ShpFolderResponse = Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Uri $RestApiUrl `
  -UseDefaultCredentials `
  -Method Get `
  -Headers @{
        "Accept" = "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }

$Files = $ShpFolderResponse.d.results

$Doc = $Files | where Name -eq $DocumentName

$driver = Start-SeDriver `
  -Browser Edge `
  -StartUrl $SiteCollectionUrl `
  -Size 1080x800 `
  -State default `
  -ImplicitWait 50

$WopiUrl = "$SiteCollectionUrl/_layouts/WopiFrame2.aspx?" +
  "sourcedoc={$($Doc.UniqueId)}&action=view"

Set-SeUrl -Url $WopiUrl
Switch-SeFrame 0 # Enter the OOS realm
sleep 1

try {# getting OOS MainApp element
  $MainApp = Get-SeElement -By Id 'MainApp' -Timeout 5 -EA Stop  # Get OOS App info
  [string[]]$MainAppText = $Mainapp.Text.Split("`r")             # Copy Text to array
}
catch {# any terminting errors occurred such as not getting MainApp
  return @('Error', 'OOS MainApp could not be found.')
}

To actually detect any errors with the rendering, you need to look for any error messages as well (not included in this answer as it adds to much to length and complexity).
